# I'm expected to create a bird app so now i'm stuck

Tags: kotlin

functionality, the user must be able to change their settings including but not limited to the following:
o Toggle between using the metric system (kilometres) or using the imperial system
(miles)
o The maximum distance that the user is willing to travel to a bird watching hotspot

```
class SettingsActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var switchMetric: Switch
    private lateinit var switchImperial: Switch
    private lateinit var maxDistanceSeekbar: SeekBar
    private lateinit var maxDistanceTextView: TextView
    // Add more UI elements for other settings as needed

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings)

        switchMetric = findViewById(R.id.switch1)
        switchImperial = findViewById(R.id.switch2)
        maxDistanceSeekbar = findViewById(R.id.maxDistanceSeekbar)
        maxDistanceTextView = findViewById(R.id.maxDistanceTextView)
        // Initialize other UI elements for additional settings

        // Handle the metric switch
        switchMetric.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // Metric system is selected
                switchImperial.isChecked = !isChecked
                // Update user preferences accordingly
                updateUserPreferences("metric")
            }
        }

        // Handle the imperial switch
        switchImperial.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
            if (isChecked) {
                // Imperial system is selected
                switchMetric.isChecked = !isChecked
                // Update user preferences accordingly
                updateUserPreferences("imperial")
            }
        }

        // Handle the maximum distance seekbar
        maxDistanceSeekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener {
            override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
                // Update the displayed maximum distance
                maxDistanceTextView.text = "$progress km" // or "$progress miles" for imperial
                // Update user preferences accordingly
                updateUserPreferences("max_distance", progress)
            }

            override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}

            override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {}
        })

        // Initialize settings based on user preferences
        initializeSettings()
    }

    // Function to update user preferences in your database or shared preferences
    private fun updateUserPreferences(setting: String, value: Any? = null) {
        // Implement logic to update user preferences
    }

    // Function to initialize settings based on user preferences
    private fun initializeSettings() {
        // Implement logic to retrieve user preferences and update the UI elements
        // Example: If user prefers the metric system, set switchMetric.isChecked = true
    }
}
```

I'm expecting the user to use my switches

Comment: Hello, this site is only for specific programming questions. This one is too vague for us to be able to help. If there is a specific piece of this problem that you cannot solve, please describe it in detail and what you tried so we can understand what information you need.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.